# adding a class when another is activated

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, class

When I have a menu toggled to on, I would like to change the class of the entire body of the website to add padding for the menu.. I am attempting this in wordpress' functions php but it doesn't affect anything when clicked. Any ideas? The whole site works fine otherwise, if i scroll down as in the function above mine, the masthead fixed is added to the body class.

my own javascript snippet:

```
if ($(' #primary-navigation' ).hasClass( 'site-navigation .primary-navigation .toggled-on' )) {
    body.addClass( 'menu-padding' );
} else {
    body.removeClass( 'menu-padding' );
}
```

body variable in the javascript

```
function( $ ) {
    var body    = $( 'body' ),
        _window = $( window );
```

snippet in place of window width function:

```
if ( _window.width() > 781 ) {
    var mastheadHeight = $( '#masthead' ).height(),
        toolbarOffset, mastheadOffset;

    if ( mastheadHeight > 48 ) {
        body.removeClass( 'masthead-fixed' );
    }

    if ( body.is( '.header-image' ) ) {
        toolbarOffset  = body.is( '.admin-bar' ) ? $( '#wpadminbar' ).height() : 0;
        mastheadOffset = $( '#masthead' ).offset().top - toolbarOffset;

        _window.on( 'scroll.twentyfourteen', function() {
            if ( _window.scrollTop() > mastheadOffset && mastheadHeight < 49 ) {
                body.addClass( 'masthead-fixed' );
            } else {
                body.removeClass( 'masthead-fixed' );
            }
        } );
    }

    if ($(' #primary-navigation' ).hasClass( 'site-navigation .primary-navigation .toggled-on' )) {
        body.addClass( 'menu-padding' );
    } else {
        body.removeClass( 'menu-padding' );
    }
}
```

im adding my javascript in the midst of the masthead fixing in wordpress because this function only works when the screen resolution is higher than 781 pixels.

css for the padding to be added for the menu

```
.menu-padding .site-main {
    margin-top: 48px;
}
```

body div:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

navigation menu:

```
<nav id="primary-navigation" class="site-navigation primary-navigation" role="navigation">
    <button class="menu-toggle">Menu function</button>
</nav>
```

navigation class when clicked:

```
<nav id="primary-navigation" class="site-navigation primary-navigation toggled-on" role="navigation">
    <button class="menu-toggle">Menu function</button>
</nav>
```

site-main div:

```
<div id="main" class="site-main">content<div/>
```

Comment: What exactly is `body`? Is it a jQuery object?

Comment: the body function is just calling to the body tag in the html. added function code to clarify

Answer (score 0):

I'm not answer to the question directly but to add/change a class depending on the windows size, why not use the css 3 : @media all and (max-width: 750px) { ... your css definition for this screen size ... } ?

Comment: I have css values for the screen size, this is a script that adds a class based on a toggle of a button, only at a certain size window frame. the function doesnt matter below 780.

Answer (score 0):

In your "own javascript snippet" code, how did you execute this one ? Because it execute only once if you don't put a listener on your button div (like *.onclick())